# Changing encoding of the file downloaded from SFTP from UTF-16 to UTF-16

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have process where function accesses SFTP, downloads file if it's zip then unpack it and streams what's inside to Google Cloud storage. Function that I'm using to GCS upload streams files from BytesIO format.
Everything worked great until files started coming in UTF-16 format. How can I adjust my function to actually account for it and make sure uploaded file has utf-8 ecnoding. This is what I tried so far, but with no luck.

```
    with io.BytesIO() as fl:
        self.sftp.getfo(file_name, fl)
        fl.seek(0)
        file = fl.read()
        file.decode("utf-16").encode("utf-8")
        f = io.BytesIO(file)
        gcs_blob_name = file_name + "_" + '.csv'
        with GCSObjectStreamUpload(client=gcs, bucket_name=gcs_bucket, blob_name=gcs_blob_name) as gcss:
            for i in f:
                gcss.write(i)
```

Comment: `file.decode("utf-16").encode("utf-8")` returns the translated data.  You need to assign it to something ... `file = file.decode("utf-16").encode("utf-8")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it with codecs package and adding extra encoding in the loop.

```
import codecs

def upload_from_csv_to_gcs(self,file_name,gcs,gcs_bucket):
    with io.BytesIO() as fl:
        self.sftp.getfo(file_name, fl)
        fl.seek(0)
        rows = codecs.iterdecode(fl, 'utf-16')
        gcs_blob_name = file_name + "_" + '.csv'
        with GCSObjectStreamUpload(client=gcs, bucket_name=gcs_bucket, blob_name=gcs_blob_name) as gcss:
            for i in rows:
                gcss.write(i.encode("utf-8"))
        return gcs_blob_name
```